# Is it really necessary to propagate context through superclasses to create a simple bitmap from drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-context

I have a simple problem, which has been answered many times on SO before, but I don't understand the answers and I can't get my code to work.

I want to create a bitmap from a drawable.

```
public class Helicopter extends Sprite {
    private Context context;
    private Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heli1_east_rot);
    public Helicopter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }
}

public class TitleScreen extends State {
    private Helicopter heli;
    public TitleScreen(Context c) {
        heli = new Helicopter(c);
   }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Game game = new Game(this, null);
     game.pushState(new TitleScreen(game.getContext()));
     setContentView(game);
    }
}
```

I have also tried `super.getGame().getContext()` in the TitleScreen class, but both attempts gives the same error in LogCat:

> 01-26 13:28:32.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.helloandroid/com.example.helloandroid.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference

Why does it have to be so hard to create a bitmap, when I can access the drawable like this `private Image wallVerImage = new Image(R.drawable.heli);`without any reference to the context?
How do I fix my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the context in

```
private Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heli1_east_rot);
```

does not specified, so you cannot refer to resources. Put initialization here:

```
 public Helicopter(Context c) {
        context = c;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heli1_east_rot);
    }
```

Comment: Obviously. Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider creation of a `Helicopter`:

```
public class Helicopter extends Sprite {
    private Context context;
    private Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heli1_east_rot);
    public Helicopter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }
}
```

First, an object is created with all fields set to `0` or `null`. Then, `bitmap`'s initializer works:

```
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heli1_east_rot);
```

But the value stored to `context` is still `null`. You get an NPE.

If you had not have an NPE, after that the code in the constructor would be executed, setting `context` to `c`.

***It may sound counter-intuitive, but you can see `null` values in initialized fields when your code executes in initializers and static initializers.***

Example:

```
class X {
    int a = getB();
    int b = 5;
    int getB() { return b; }
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
    X x = new X();
    System.out.println("x.a="+x.a+"  x.b="+x.b);
    }
}
```

runs and prints:

```
$ java A
x.a=0  x.b=5
```